# Is it possible to use reportviewer control in ASP.Net core application?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created an application using ASP.Net core. I want to generate some RDLC reports and use them in Angular. Is it possible to use reportviewer control for it?
if yes, which Nuget package should I install?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AspNetCore.Reporting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Reporting) NuGet package.

Tutorial : http://blog.geveo.com/IntegratingRDLCReportsToNetCoreProjects.